# OpenVPN multiple gateway issue (server can't access new client gateway's)

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, iptables, gateway

By default, OpenVPN gateway is 10.8.0.x, i want to add 10.8.1.x gateway additionally.

the problem :

Clients with 10.8.0.x and 10.8.1.x ip can ping the server and access via ssh. In addition, clients can perform ping and ssh tasks among themselves. However, the server can only ping devices with 10.8.0.x ip and connect via ssh. I can't get any access to 10.8.1.x.

i added static ip for clients :

client1(10.8.0.x):

```
added "ifconfig-push 10.8.0.31 255.255.0.0" to /etc/openvpn/ccd/client1
```

client2(10.8.1.x):

```
added "ifconfig-push 10.8.1.31 255.255.0.0" to /etc/openvpn/ccd/client2
```

In addition, I add the following to the resulting configs:

```
route-nopull
route 10.8.0.1
```

client 1(10.8.0.x) :

```
client
route-nopull
route 10.8.0.1
dev tun
proto udp
remote 11.111.111.111 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
block-outside-dns
verb 3
```

client 2(10.8.1.x) :

```
client
route-nopull
route 10.8.0.1
dev tun
proto udp
remote 11.111.111.111 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
block-outside-dns
verb 3
```

server.conf :

```
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
client-to-client
local 11.111.111.111
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0
server-ipv6 fddd:1194:1194:1194::/64
push "redirect-gateway def1 ipv6 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
explicit-exit-notify
```

server iptable :

```
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 243K   51M ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn
   72  7070 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
 2602  200K ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp any
 269K   53M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
22178 1325K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 136K packets, 7731K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
26413   16M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 1760  214K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     10.8.0.0/24          anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     10.8.0.0/24          anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 632K packets, 124M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   72  7070 ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      anywhere             anywhere            
 2442  177K ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, i couldn't find a solution. I haven't researched too much since i switched to Tailscale.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think I found a solution: you have to manually add an ip address to the server side tun device. The general documentation and online forum resoponse on the matter is horrid.